# Get own IP in Java Servlets

Tags: servlets

Is it possible to get the IP of the own server in a Java Servlet?

I am sending an activation link if somebody signs up to my service. Since I want to install the virtual machine where my service is installed on different machines, it is necessarry, that the Java Servlet which sends the email knows the own IP.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: use a public API that tells you your ip. Eg. `https://api.ipify.org/?format=json`

Comment: You don't need the IP address, you need the hostname, and that is available via a request property.

Comment: @EJP: How does that work? What is the difference between hostname and IP?

Comment: @progNewbie That is an *extremely* basic question about IP networking.

Comment: Even if you hate my answer but i would still recommend to use java.net API. The reason is portability if you use java api same will work across all environments Win/Linux etc..., There will be multiple results based on number of network cards and additional loopback and localhost addresses. You need to filter on these to find the required IP.

Comment: @redFIVE Can you write this as an answer please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
String serverIP = request.getLocalAddr();
```